# Rsync-like solution on Windows?

Tags: windows, lamp

I have a web application that needs to deploy to both Linux and Windows. I use rsync for Linux, and robocopy to deploy to Windows. Problem is that I have thousands of files and the Robocopy takes too much time to sync.  I understand that because robocopy does not have a server to compare files.

I looked into the new web deploy tools released from Microsoft, and found that it is way too complicated (is that just me?).

Anyway is there a simple sync solution on Windows?

Comment: What is your problem with robocopy? It *is* the Windows equivalent of rsync.

Comment: Why don't you use rsync?

Answer (score 2):

There is a cygwin rsync available if it's rsync you want: http://rsync.net/resources/howto/windows_rsync.html

Comment: ...and that's only one of [many rsync ports for Windows](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=rsync+for+windows)!

Answer (score 0):

Grsync is best and free , don't need cygwin :-

http://sourceforge.net/projects/grsync-win/

Another alternative :-

http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/DeltaCopy.jsp